# tcpdf неправильное отображение шрифта

Tags: php, tcpdf

есть текст например 'אַשְׁרֵי'

использую шрифт 'Shofar'

Подключаю:

```
$shofar = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . './shofar.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);
```

Вывод:

```
$html = '<font face="'.$shofar.'" style="text-align:justify;">'.$text.'</font>';
```

Вывод в pdf:

```
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
```

И в созданном файле pdf символы букв улетают влево, как это исправить?
https://prnt.sc/nfaqtBua3x-e
На сайте к примеру отображается правильно и просто если pdf создать вставить туда этот текст и выбрать шрифт тоже все правильно отображает.

Comment: Попробуйте удалить файл fonts/shofar.php, тогда таблица ширин шрифта должна перекомпилиться.